# Cache data from Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-product-api

I've been using node.js and express to search using amazon product advertising API, it now works as a web API endpoint so that I can get data by the link:

```
my_host/amazon/{search_catgegory}/{keyword}/{page}
```

However, there's a limitation on amazon API, it only returns max 10 items each time. So, I want to cache the search result in my own database, then I can have, say, 50 items return upon each query.

My idea is to use node-cron to schedule my task to achieve what I want (e.g. get first 10 pages of search results) on every Monday midnight.

there are 2 questions:
1) how to effectively get my result, do I simply call the API multiple times like below?

```
my_host/amazon/{search_catgegory}/{keyword}/1,
my_host/amazon/{search_catgegory}/{keyword}/2,
my_host/amazon/{search_catgegory}/{keyword}/3,
...
my_host/amazon/{search_catgegory}/{keyword}/10
```

or should I wrap each API query into a promise, and then use something like promise.all() to get all data I want?

2) should I have the web API service (i.e. the original express app) and this new cron task (i.e. 'preload' data from amazon) in the same node application? or should I do it in separate apps?